# GET API Request - Form Data Types

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

I am currently trying to pull data from Kentico using a C# Web API, and I can successfully pull the data, but I also plan on storing it into a database.

Using a call like : `/rest/bizformitem.bizform.contactus`

I receive back all of the data within the form, but since I am storing these values into the database I would like to know the field data type for that form name/value.

Most API references have lists such as: `ID:USER_ID | Type:int | Desc:User ID Form Field`.

I am trying to find a reference via the API or documentation for these values within the form, so any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look in the CMS_Class database table.  Find your class, then there is the ClassFormDefinition field, it has XML that shows all the fields with the types.

Load the XML into a XmlDocument, then selectnodes for //field[@column="YourColumnName"], below is a sample of the XML

```
<field column="CultureName" visible="true" columntype="text" fieldtype="CustomUserControl" system="true" columnsize="200" publicfield="false" guid="7b7c2f84-da09-4874-aade-a4d3b77b975d">
```

Now note, the columntype are kind of Kentico specific naming, so you have to do a switch to convert it to either .Net classes or SQL Database ones.

```
switch (fieldType)
        {
            case "longtext":
            case "text":
            default:
                dt.Columns.Add(fieldName, typeof(string));
                break;
            case "binary":
                dt.Columns.Add(fieldName, typeof(byte[]));
                break;
            case "boolean":
                dt.Columns.Add(fieldName, typeof(Boolean));
                break;
            case "date":
                dt.Columns.Add(fieldName, typeof(DateTime));
                break;
            case "datetime":
                dt.Columns.Add(fieldName, typeof(DateTime));
                break;
            case "decimal":
                dt.Columns.Add(fieldName, typeof(Decimal));
                break;
            case "double":
                dt.Columns.Add(fieldName, typeof(Double));
                break;
            case "integer":
                dt.Columns.Add(fieldName, typeof(Int32));
                break;
            case "longinteger":
                dt.Columns.Add(fieldName, typeof(Int64));
                break;
            case "timespan":
                dt.Columns.Add(fieldName, typeof(TimeSpan));
                break;
            case "guid":
                dt.Columns.Add(fieldName, typeof(Guid));
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Is the CMS_Class database table accessible via the REST API?

Comment: Yes, you can get the data via `/rest/cms.class/all`

Comment: @rocky Is there a reason when trying `/rest/cms.form/all or /rest/cms.class/all` I receive a 403 error?

Comment: Do other requests work fine? (Make sure you have configured everything according to: https://docs.kentico.com/k10/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service/configuring-the-rest-service) People often forget about the web.config setting, for instance.